# Verify if clicking something get you out of the app in appium

Tags: android, ios, appium

I would like to know if it's possible to test that if I click on a element in my app (android or ios) it opens another app over mine

For example

- If I click on a publicity does it goes out of the application and open a browser or not
- If I click on a button to open another app does it goes correctly to the other one or to the store or not

etc

Answer (score 1):

Yeah ! You can verify both points. Use `String getCurrentActivity=driver.currentActivity();` if you know your second apps activities then directly verify activity against current one.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes it is possible. Simply using Appium's inspector go throught your scenario:

> If I click on a publicity does it goes out of the application and open a browser or not

And then check if Inspector found particular elements that you can base on in your tests - check if those web view has some id's, name or xpath.

Answer (score 0):

pick an id from your app, after exiting your app check that id , if its present your in your app still, if its not present ,you have exited your app